# Converting a list to one row data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
arg0 <- list(code = "a", n = rep(10, 3))
```

The number of objects in a list is variable. The objects of the list are vectors -- only one dimensional objects.

I want to make a procedure to convert the list to a one row data.frame like this:

```
> data.frame(code = "a", n.1 = 10, n.2 = 10, n.3 = 10)
  code n.1 n.2 n.3
1    a  10  10  10
```

I have this solution currently:

```
a <- stack(arg0)
b <- data.frame(t(a[,1]))
names(b) <- a[,2]
b <- data.frame(b)
```

Where `b` is almost the result I want to achieve:

```
> b
  code  n n.1 n.2
1    a 10  10  10
```

Two questions:

1. Is there more elegant way to achieve the result?
2. Do you have any idea how to get the numbering of the duplicate colnames like `c(n.1,
   n.2, n.3)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to keep the different data types of the list's objects, the following command can be used:

```
data.frame(lapply(arg0, function(x) t(data.frame(x))))
```

The output:

```
  code n.1 n.2 n.3
x    a  10  10  10
```

The values in columns two to four are still numeric.

Comment: Accepted because of preserving data types -- the extra feature I did not ask in the question but I was thinking about it. It is surprise for me how the naming of the objects is organised in R. Different row names are assigned to the same result in these two examples: `foo <- function(x) t(data.frame(x)); foo(arg0[[1]])` and `t(data.frame(arg0[[1]]))`. Did not know also that `lapply` preserves the object names from the argument list. Thanks for educating answer!

Comment: Another similar solution: data.frame(lapply(arg0, function(x) t(matrix(x))))

Answer (score 11):

This is one way:

```
data.frame(t(unlist(arg0)))
#   code n1 n2 n3
# 1    a 10 10 10
```

Comment: This won't work since it would make the 10's be a factor.
x <- list(code = "a", n = rep(10, 3))
xx <- data.frame(t(unlist(x)))
sapply(xx, typeof)
sapply(xx, class)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `write.table` and `read.table` on the transposed unlisted data. I have use the clipboard as an intermediate step to hold the table.

```
write.table(t(unlist(arg0)),"clipboard")
read.table("clipboard")
  code n1 n2 n3
1    a 10 10 10
```

Comment: This won't work since it would make the 10's be a factor.
```
x <- list(code = "a", n = rep(10, 3))
xx <- data.frame(t(unlist(x)))
sapply(xx, typeof)
sapply(xx, class)
```

Comment: @TalGalili `read.table` will re-interpret the data in the usual manner.

Comment: But this relies on read.table to make good choices on a character vector. Would it work if n had a factor?

Comment: You can specify choices with `colClasses` and to some extent `stringsAsFactors` if the default choices are not suitable